If this script contain any scam from provider
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

// Interface for ERC20 token and Uniswap V2 Router
interface IERC20 {
    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint);
    function transfer(address recipient, uint amount) external returns (bool);
    function approve(address spender, uint amount) external returns (bool);
    function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint amount) external returns (bool);
}

interface IUniswapV2Router {
    function swapExactTokensForTokens(uint amountIn, uint amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline) external returns (uint[] memory amounts);
    function getAmountsOut(uint amountIn, address[] calldata path) external view returns (uint[] memory amounts);
}

contract SimpleArbitrage {
    address private owner;
    uint256 private minFunding = 0.001 ether;
    
    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Not the owner");
        _;
    }

    function swap(address router, address tokenIn, address tokenOut, uint256 amountIn) private {
        IERC20(tokenIn).approve(router, amountIn);
        address;
        path[0] = tokenIn;
        path[1] = tokenOut;
        uint deadline = block.timestamp + 300;
        IUniswapV2Router(router).swapExactTokensForTokens(amountIn, 1, path, address(this), deadline);
    }

    function getAmountOutMin(address router, address tokenIn, address tokenOut, uint256 amountIn) internal view returns (uint256) {
        address;
        path[0] = tokenIn;
        path[1] = tokenOut;
        uint256[] memory amountsOut = IUniswapV2Router(router).getAmountsOut(amountIn, path);
        return amountsOut[amountsOut.length - 1];
    }

    function frontRun(address router1, address router2, address token1, address token2, uint256 amount) internal {
        uint startBalance = IERC20(token1).balanceOf(address(this));
        swap(router1, token1, token2, amount);
        uint token2Amount = IERC20(token2).balanceOf(address(this));
        swap(router2, token2, token1, token2Amount);
        uint endBalance = IERC20(token1).balanceOf(address(this));
        require(endBalance > startBalance, "No profit made");
    }

    function estimateTriDexTrade(address router1, address router2, address router3, address token1, address token2, address token3, uint256 amount) internal view returns (uint256) {
        uint amtBack1 = getAmountOutMin(router1, token1, token2, amount);
        uint amtBack2 = getAmountOutMin(router2, token2, token3, amtBack1);
        uint amtBack3 = getAmountOutMin(router3, token3, token1, amtBack2);
        return amtBack3;
    }

    function startArbitrage() public payable {
        require(msg.value >= minFunding, "Insufficient funding");
        // Example usage: replace with actual router addresses and tokens
        address router1 = 0x...; // Router address
        address router2 = 0x...; // Router address
        address token1 = 0x...; // Token address
        address token2 = 0x...; // Token address
        uint256 amount = msg.value; // Use the entire funding amount
        frontRun(router1, router2, token1, token2, amount);
    }

    function recoverEth() public onlyOwner {
        payable(owner).transfer(address(this).balance);
    }

    receive() external payable {}
}


You should never deploy a contract that you don't understand its working. As it is the code doesn't do anything malicious but it has some red flags like using private for variables without any need, a function named frontRun that doesn't do any front running. There is no such thing as a solidity front run bot, solidity is executed inside the EVM and for a bot to do front running it has to be executed outside.
